# Proof that $\inf [(f + g)(D)]$ is greater then or equal to$ \inf f(D) + \inf g(D)$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $D$ be a nonempty set and suppose that $f: D \to R$ and $g: D \to R$. Define the function $f +g : D \to R$ by $(f + g)(x) = f(x) + g(x)$. If $f(D)$ and $g(D)$ are bounded below, then prove that $(f + g)(D)$ is bounded below and
$\inf[(f + g)(D)]$ is greater then or equal to $\inf f(D) + \inf g(D)$. Use an example to show that this inequality can occur.

What has me so tripped up here is the proper use of the completness property of infima. I  can't see how that trait would apply to the given inequalities. Would that even be the right property to apply here?

Answer (score 0):

The chain of thinking here is
$$\inf_{x\in D}f(x)+\inf_{x\in D}g(x)=\inf_{x\in D}f(x)+\inf_{y\in D}g(y)=\inf_{x\in D,y\in D}[f(x)+g(y)]\leq \inf_{x\in D}[f(x)+g(x)],$$
where the first equality follows cause $x$ is just an index variable; the second one cause $f(x)$ is a constant for the $y-$infimun and the same goes for $g(y)$ with respect to the $x-$infimun; and the inequality follows cause you're restricting yourself to $y=x$, which means less posible values and so a posible bigger inf-value.

For a example in which the strict inequality is attained suffices to take $f$ non-constant and $g=-f$. If this is the case then there are $x_1,x_2\in D$ such that $f(x_1)<f(x_2)$. Then $\inf_{x\in D}[f(x)+g(x)]=\inf_{x\in D}[0]=0$ (this always happens if $g=-f$) but $\inf_{x\in D}f(x)+\inf_{x\in D}g(x)\leq f(x_1)-f(x_2)<0.$

Comment: I can follow that logic..but the problem never made use of a y variable here ?

Comment: Yes I guess so. It doesn't matter how you call an index variable, I just treated them separately to explain more clearly what is the argument. In fact, to write it in the detail I did you need to use two different names so the expression just before the inequality expresses what you want.

Comment: Ah, so x or y doesn't matter? and adding two x's to the argument won't change the logic?

Comment: Notice that here we only used estimations...

Comment: What I say is that it doesn't matter what name yoy give to a index. For example, $\sum_{j=1}^{100}j$ has the same value if you express it like that or like $\sum_{k=1}^{100}k$ (which is $5050$). You are just naming a variable which will run through the same values if you call it $y$ or if you call it "$fish$."

Comment: When working with variables you just need to keep in mind that it just represent an indetermined object and that it is the object itself you're dealing with. In your example $y$ is an element of $D$ and $x$ another one, both indetermined.

Comment: Makes sense, I see you use the completness property of Infima. Any other properties utilized?

Comment: What do you call completness property of infima?

Comment: Nevermind, I got that worked out. But IM still confused on the inequality part. You say the inequality is any f with f(x) < 0 for some x and g = -f. is there a formal proof to this?

Comment: Actually I was a little sloppy. It suffices to take $f$ non-constant and $g=-f$. If this is the case then there are $x_1,x_2\in D$ such that $f(x_1)<f(x_2)$. Then $\inf_{x\in D}[f(x)+g(x)]=\inf_{x\in D}[0]=0$ (this always happens if $g=-f$) but $\inf_{x\in D}f(x)+\inf_{x\in D}g(x)\leq f(x_1)-f(x_2)<0.$

Comment: Ok thanks. I get that now. It just seems the wording was a bit used. so f non constant sill represens any f() < 0 for some x and still we have g = -f?

Comment: No. It is as stated.